# Unable to see added content editor web part on edit page option share point 2013 in wiki pages

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to add `ContentEditorWebPart` on the home page of some sites. I am using a `powershell` script to perform this action.

The WebPart is getting added to the page, and I am able to see it, however if I try to edit it, I am not able to see the added WebPart. On WebPart pages everything works just fine.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
# function to set the content editor webpart
function SetContentEditorWebPart($path)
{
# get contents from csv file
$csvcontents=Import-Csv -Path $path
foreach($site in $csvContents)
{
#iterate through each site and add content editor webpart on the home page of the site
$url=$site.'Site Url'
$website=Get-SPSite -Identity $url
$web=$website.RootWeb
$wpmgr=$web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($web.RootFolder.WelcomePage,[system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.personalizationscope]::Shared)
$contenteditorwebpart=New-Object microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.ContentEditorWebPart
$contenteditorwebpart.Title="Site Migration Information"
$contenteditorwebpart.ChromeType=[system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.PartChromeType]::TitleAndBorder
[system.Xml.XmlDocument]$content=New-Object system.Xml.XmlDocument
[system.Xml.XmlElement]$contentxml=$content.CreateElement("MigrationContent")
$contentxml.InnerText="Your SharePoint site is ready!"+" "+"<a href="+$site.Test+">Here</a>"+" "+"is the link for the New site"
$contenteditorwebpart.Content=$contentxml
$wpmgr.AddWebPart($contenteditorwebpart,"Body",1)
$wpmgr.SaveChanges($contenteditorwebpart)
}

}
# Provide the path of Csv File containing site urls and call the function
SetContentEditorWebPart("Path for the Csv File")
```

Comment: Hmm... this sounds like a problem that people encounter [when adding content editor web parts to wiki pages](https://sharepoint.hannahswain.eu/2013/04/23/sharepoint-and-the-disappearing-webparts/) even when they're not doing it programmatically. Are you able to edit the content editor web part **without** editing the wiki page?

Comment: Yes  i am able to edit the content editor web part